# Android: Update SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, insert-update

I am new to Android. I am trying to update information in sqlite database. Most of the time I able to update the information but sometimes my phone come out with error of updating. I had debugged many times, it shows nothing wrong with my code. I am using Android Version 5.1.1 Lollipop as testing tool. Most of the times, updating sqlite is working fine but sometimes the application will crash.

The following is my code update code. Please tell me what's wrong with my code.

```
public void updateArticle(String NewName, String oldName) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_ARTICLENAME, NewName);
    db.update(TABLE_ARTICLE, values, COLUMN_ARTICLENAME + " = '" + oldName + "'", null);
    db.close();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: *"but sometimes my phone come out with error of updating"* What error exactly?

Comment: What is the error on your studio ?

Comment: Actually is not error, it just cannot update latest information. For example if Old Name is Java Tutorial and update new name to Java Programming, I debug and see that is no updating to sqlite. But sometimes I update, it's update successfully. I feel something weird.

Comment: Sorry is not error, is just cannot update for sometimes but sometimes I able to update. I debug many times already, it shows no problem with my code.

Comment: When you are debugging put a break point in the first line and make sure that the NewName and oldName values are what you expect and that oldName exists in the database. Also make sure you replace any single quotes with two single quotes, if you don't do that though it should throw an exception when you run the update query.

Comment: That is the basic rule of debugging. Of course I know put a break point pn the line. What I means sometime NewName and oldName values are what you expect and that oldName exists in the database. But sometimes NewName and oldName values are what you expect and that oldName does not exists in the database. Something very weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must update the version of the db too !

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try
        {
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
            Message.message(context, "onUpgrade called");
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            Message.message(context, "" + e);            }
    }
```

with the DATABASE_VERSION = 1

Comment: Yes, I have onUpgrade function to update the version of db.

Answer (score -1):

There can be more than one Java Tutorial so when cursor started looking rows it update different row which is not your expected row. Imagine that there is a listview and your rows listed on it. Take item with id and update it is a more good coding practice. You can have look following links i hope it will help your problem.

http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sqlite-example/
http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html

Comment: Thanks for you reply

Comment: Unfortunalety we took mines reputation :)